# Many to Many joins Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about many to many relationships in Oracle, and a way to join them in a query.

I've pasted my (textbook) example along with some inserts to make it clear. The query I want to build needs to extract books along with their respective authors **and** other authors that have no book yet.

I've been working with:

```
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.book_title
FROM books b, authors a, publish p
WHERE b.book_id = p.book_id(+) AND a.author_id = p.author_id;
```

However, that fails to do the trick.

Comment: Usage of (+) has been superseded, partly because it's too cryptic to understand. If such a join does not work, you can try to put the exception on the other side of the join, but one should also be aware why either solution works, and the other not. Often, just the side is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.book_title
FROM authors a
LEFT OUTER JOIN publish p ON a.author_id = p.author_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN books b ON b.book_id = p.book_id;
```

The trick is to use an **OUTER JOIN**, if you like to get the authors without books, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book
BookId PK
BookName

Author
AuthorId PK
AuthorName

BookAuthor
BookId PK, FK
AuthorId PK, FK

select b.BookName, a.AuthorName
from BookAuthor ba
inner join Book b on b.BookId = ba.BookId 
inner join Author a on a.AuthorId = ba.AuthorId
where b.BookId =: bookId;
```